# Windows 10 anniversary upgrade - border around window screenshot

Tags: windows-10-v1607, print-screen

After the Windows 10 Anniversary upgrade, the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> combo captures a border of some size around a window, as in the screenshot below. Is it possible to have only the active window captured?

[image]

Comment: I have fully updated Win10 Anniversary (14393.222) and Alt+PrtScn works normally.

Comment: I checked again and confirmed that it is due to the program I used which did not capture the correct region after the upgrade.